# Is there a way to include a custom user class in RTE link wizard?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Users would like to add custom classes to links in RTE link wizard.  I don't see any documentation about this feature.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On TYPO3 7 you have to add the followint Page TSConfig:

```
RTE.classesAnchor.myown-link {
  class = myown-link
  type = page
  titleText = My Own Link
  altText = My Own Link
  }

RTE.default.buttons.link.properties.class.allowedClasses := addToList(myown-link)
RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := addToList(myown-link)
```

See the [documentation here](https://docs.typo3.org/p/friendsoftypo3/rtehtmlarea/master/en-us/Configuration/PageTsconfig/classesAnchor/Index.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881884/what-is-the-right-configuration-for-the-rte-to-show-my-own-css-classes-as-select), too

Comment: I don't want a dropdown with my class but a text input where the user can put his own class.